# Area of one of four regions within a rectangle

Tags: geometry, puzzle, triangles, area, rectangles

There is a figure below (a rectangle). You can see different colors depicting different regions of the figure. The labels on the top of a region defines the area of that region.

Can you find the area of the green shaded region labelled with a question mark?

[image: embedded image]

Source:
http://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/mathematical-picture-area-problem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved with similar triangles property.

The White triangle is similar to the Red one
Now Ratio of sides is $2:3$ (as the ratio of areas = ratio of bases if the height is same)

Seeking that, area of the white triangle $= \frac{9}{4} \times$ area of the red triangle $= \frac{9}{2}$
Following all the above, the Green region = $5.5$ units

Comment: I know how to do it, but I cannot find your "Yellow triangle".

Comment: This is a copy of the answer given in the OP's reference, which was not well explained, although it gave the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved with similar triangles property.

Answer (score -3):

Combine the red and blue triangles to form a red-blue 45-45-90 isosceles right triangle and assume that the two sides equal 3.1622 cm and that the hypotenuse is 4.47203 cm with an area of 5 cm<sup>2</sup>. 

Split the 90 degree angle of the combined red-blue isosceles right triangle into two angles of 56.31 degrees and 33.69 degrees to form two triangles with an area ratio of 3 cm<sup>2</sup> and 2 cm<sup>2</sup>.
$$A = 1/2 * bh$$
since A = 3 - 2.50 because 2.50 is the area when the red-blue isosceles right triangle is split into two equal parts 
$$0.50 = 1/2 * b * 2.236$$
$$b = 1 / 2.236$$
$$b = 0.4472$$
$$tan(x) = b / h$$
$$tan(x) = 0.4472 / 2.236$$
$$tan(x) = 0.2$$
$$x = arctan(0.2)$$
$$x = 11.31^o$$

blue scalene angle = 45° + 11.31° 
blue scalene angle = 56.31° 

red scalene angle = 90° - 56.31° 
red scalene angle = 33.69° 

blue triangle = 56.31° to form an area of 3 cm<sup>2</sup> 
red triangle = 33.69° to form an area of 2 cm<sup>2</sup> 

3 cm<sup>2</sup> blue triangle: 
45° + 56.31° = 101.31° 
180° - 101.31° = 78.69° 

2 cm<sup>2</sup> red triangle: 
45° + 33.69° = 78.69° 
180° - 78.69° = 101.31° 

3 cm<sup>2</sup> blue triangle : 45° - 56.31° - 78.69° degree scalene triangle 
2 cm<sup>2</sup> red triangle : 45° - 33.69° - 101.31° degree scalene triangle 

to calculate the area of the white triangle, we combine the blue and the white triangle which becomes a blue-white right triangle with a apex angle of 56.31°. after getting the area of the blue-white triangle, we subtract the blue area which is 3 cm<sup>2</sup> to get the area of the white triangle. 

tan(56.31°) = long side of the white triangle / 3.1622 
long side of the white triangle = tan(56.31°) * 3.1622 
long side of the white triangle = 4.7433 cm 

Calculating the area of the rectangle: 
**area of the rectangle** = 4.7433 * 3.1622 = 15 cm<sup>2</sup> 

area of the combined blue-white right triangle = area of the rectangle / 2 = 15 / 2 
area of the combined blue-white right triangle = 7.50 cm<sup>2</sup> 

**area of the white triangle** = area of the combined blue-white right triangle - area of the blue triangle = 7.50 - 3 
area of the white triangle = 4.50 cm<sup>2</sup> 

area of the rectangle = red + blue + white + green 
15 = 2 + 3 + 4.50 + green 
15 = 9.50 + green 
area of the green triangle = 15 - 9.50 
**area of the green triangle** = 5.50 cm<sup>2</sup> 

in summary of the areas: 

area of the rectangle = 15 cm<sup>2</sup> 
red triangle = 2 cm<sup>2</sup> 
blue triangle = 3 cm<sup>2</sup> 
white triangle = 4.50 cm<sup>2</sup> 
green triangle = 5.50 cm<sup>2</sup>

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: ChatGPT still is not able to do maths correctly. It is not true that the apex angles of the red and blue triangles have the same ratio as the areas of those two triangles.

Comment: I recalculated the area ratio and the correct calculation to form two triangles with ratios of 3 cm^2 and 2 cm^2 is 56.31 degrees and 33.69 degrees. That is the case when the combined red-blue 45-45-90 isosceles right triangle is split into two scalene triangles. This is to confirm that the "area of similar triangles theorem" is acurrate.

Comment: If you have more questions, I'll be back. Hasta la vista